# How to implement OnColorChange event for jQuery Simple Color Picker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a html table with 2 columns (code as shown below)

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (DTRow vr in Model.Values)
        {
            <tr id="@vr.FieldID">
                <td>@vr.FieldName</td>
                <td><input class="RowColorField" @string.Format("id={0}{1}", vr.FieldID, "_colorField") type="text" name="colorField" value="@vr.Color"/></td>
            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
```

I am using the jQuery plugin "Really Simple Color Picker" to show color palette for the second column in the table. So I have the below code in document.ready function. When the color is changed, a request needs to be sent to the server with the new color value and the id of the row for which the color is changed. My question is how to capture these two values from that particular row?
Any ideas on how to implement this? Thanks for any help.

```
$(".RowColorField").colorPicker( {transparency: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [readme](https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker#readme) reveals that a callback can be specified in the `colorPicker` options, like this:

```
$('.RowColorField').colorPicker({
    onColorChange : function(id, newValue) {
        // send id and newValue to the server here
    }
});
```